# Creating a data table of data points above regression line

Tags: r, ggplot2, data.table, regression, mixed-models

I have a panel data set which I have fit a fixed effects model:

```
data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   year = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3),
                   progenyMean = c(90,78,92,69,86,73,82,85,91),
                   damMean = c(89,89,72,98,95,92,94,87,89)

ID, year, progenyMean, damMean
1, 1, 70, 69
1, 2, 68, 69
1, 3, 72, 72
1, 4, 69, 68
2, 1, 76, 75
2, 2, 73, 80
3, 1, 72, 74
3, 2, 75, 67
3, 3, 71, 69

# Fixed Effects Model in plm
fixed <- plm(progenyMean ~ damMean, data, model= "within", index = c("ID","year"))
```

I have plotted progenyMean vs damMean with the fixed effects regression line in blue:

[image]

**I want to identify the `ID`'s above the fixed effects regression line and create a data table of this information.** There are several data points for every unique `ID`, so it's possible for an `ID` to have points *both above and below* the regression line.

I have computed the predicted values of the fixed effects model (`fitted`) and identified the data points above the line:

```
fitted <- as.numeric(fixed$model[[1]] - fixed$residuals)
above <- data$progenyMean3Y > fitted
above
 [1]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[12] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
[23] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Is it possible to create a table using `data.table` where **each row is a unique `ID` and there are two columns, `above` and `below` which count the number of data points above/below the regression line for that `ID`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following the logic that you already layed out in your question, below is one approach to build a summary `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)
library(plm)

data <- data.frame(ID = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3),
                   year = c(1,2,3,4,1,2,1,2,3),
                   progenyMean = c(90,78,92,69,86,73,82,85,91),
                   damMean = c(89,89,72,98,95,92,94,87,89))

# Fixed Effects Model in plm
fixed <- plm(progenyMean ~ damMean, data, model= "within", index = c("ID","year"))

fitted <- as.numeric(fixed$model[[1]] - fixed$residuals)
above <- data$progenyMean > fitted

dt <- as.data.table(data)

dt[, `:=`(fitted = fixed$model[[1]] - fixed$residuals,
          above = progenyMean > fitted,
          below = progenyMean < fitted)
   ][,
     .(above = sum(above), below = sum(below)), by = "ID"][]

#>    ID above below
#> 1:  1     1     3
#> 2:  2     1     1
#> 3:  3     1     2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-08-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>